# Error on getApplicationContext() when use Toast

Tags: android

I will show a message with toast when i click on an option of a select dialog. But in eclipse appears a error in getApplicationContext().

The code of the select dialog:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
public class DialogoSeleccion extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 final String[] items = {"Español", "Inglés", "Francés"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Selección")
       .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Opción seleccionada: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                }
        });
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

The error message is:

> The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}

I can´t know how to solve this problem.

**Edit: Ok. Thanks. Solved with getActivity().getApplicationContext(). Thanks to all.**

Comment: `Toast.makeText(DialogoSeleccion.this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that specific line you are in the context of the new DialogInterface.OnClickListener and not your fragment.
you should get the Context from the fragment by:
`getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getApplicationContext()`, you may use `DialogoSeleccion.this`